# SharePoint 2013 Automatically translate new / modified documents in a document library

Tags: document-library, 2013

Is it possible to configure the machine translation service to have the word documents automatically translated to desired languages as they are added to the specified document library?

If yes, is it also possible to have the automatic translation for any changes in the documents within the specified document library?

I saw some MSDN examples showing codes to translate documents on demand (either single file or in batch ) but I am interested in creating a workflow so any new / modified documents in the specified document library will be translated to specified languages.